# How do you make a parameterized route the default route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm planning to have the home page of the application to be on this route `/list/{listId}/snippets/{snippetId}`.

I have this in my `app-routing.module.ts`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'lists',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    // NOTE: don't use patchMatch: 'full' for lazy-loaded modules
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
    canActivate: [GuessGuard],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/lists',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: '/',
      pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

Under the lazy-loaded feature module, i have this route

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    {
    path: ':listId/snippets/:snippetId',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  }
```

Logically, i can have a functionality that manually navigates to the desired route, e.g `this.router.navigate(['/lists', listId, 'snippets', 'snippetId'])` inside `HomeComponent` but it causes it to initialize the component again. This seems to be not a ideal solution as the homepage would require to be initialized twice.

Is there any solution out there that solves something similar to this scenario?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add a component to a route, angular is going to load that component. You might want to add an array of `children` to the route with path `''`. And have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in that component.

Comment: That is definitely one alternative, so instead of `HomeComponent`, i can replace it with `ChildComponent`. If i execute the navigation above, wouldn't it also re-initialize `HomeComponent` since it's the parent component?

Is there a way to set the parameterized route without calling `this.router.navigate` manually?

Comment: Angular router is smart enough to not reload the parent of children. `this.router.navigate` is the right way to implement programmatic routing using the angular router.